# R - how to execute specific code after error

Tags: r, error-handling

In my function myFunc() I want to execute specific code after error.

myFunc code:

```
if (x > 10) {y <- x
} else {y <- 0}
```

But I want myFunc to execute like bellow:

```
if (x > 10) {y <- x
} else if (error) {y <- NA
} else {y <-0}
```

Is it possible in R?

Comment: Read the online help for `tryCatch`.

Comment: What kind of error might it be? Can you give us some more context?

Comment: My script try to scrape HTML of the page. Error occurs when page is unavalible.